# Can't find dist folder after $grunt build yo angular

Tags: angularjs, heroku, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

Currently, I'm using yo angular to build my app.

```
$grunt server
```

works fine and I can test my app on localhost and I want to deploy this app into Heroku that require dist folder:

```
$grunt build
```

Although the result is fine but it doesn't create dist folder (note that I also run CMD console as Admin):
[image]

There is no dist folder:

[image]

I don't change any code in Gruntfile.js. I also create fresh app with $yo angular freshApp and run $grunt build and also no dist folder too. Do I miss some config? please help me.

Comment: Even I am facing similar such problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174628/unable-to-generate-dist-folder-in-yeoman-angular-generated-webapp Please check if you have come across this.

Comment: Have you checked your exports override in bower.json file ? you have to mention there

Comment: Share your gruntfile.