# Unable to generate "dist" folder in yeoman angular generated webapp

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am unable to generate **dist** folder in the web app built and generated using yeoman angular generator.

I am pasting the verbose of grunt build. Please check if this is helpful.

```
pdc1-f3t18r1:ShippingSolution administrator$ grunt --verbose build
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.

Registering "grunt-autoprefixer" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json...OK
Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...OK
+ autoprefixer

Registering "grunt-concurrent" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
Loading "concurrent.js" tasks...OK
+ concurrent

Registering "grunt-contrib-clean" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
Loading "clean.js" tasks...OK
+ clean

Registering "grunt-contrib-compass" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
Loading "compass.js" tasks...OK
+ compass

Registering "grunt-contrib-concat" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
Loading "concat.js" tasks...OK
+ concat

Registering "grunt-contrib-connect" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
Loading "connect.js" tasks...OK
+ connect

Registering "grunt-contrib-copy" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/package.json...OK
Loading "copy.js" tasks...OK
+ copy

Registering "grunt-contrib-cssmin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...OK
+ cssmin

Registering "grunt-contrib-htmlmin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/package.json...OK
Loading "htmlmin.js" tasks...OK
+ htmlmin

Registering "grunt-contrib-imagemin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'bin-wrapper'
>>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>     at require (module.js:380:17)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle/lib/index.js:3:18)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
+ jshint

Registering "grunt-contrib-uglify" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...OK
+ uglify

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Registering "grunt-filerev" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-filerev/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-filerev/package.json...OK
Loading "filerev.js" tasks...OK
+ filerev

Registering "grunt-google-cdn" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/package.json...OK
Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...OK
+ cdnify

Registering "grunt-newer" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-newer/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-newer/package.json...OK
Loading "newer.js" tasks...OK
+ any-newer, newer, newer-clean, newer-postrun

Registering "grunt-ng-annotate" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/package.json...OK
Loading "ng-annotate.js" tasks...OK
+ ngAnnotate

Registering "grunt-svgmin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
Loading "svgmin.js" tasks...OK
+ svgmin

Registering "grunt-usemin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-usemin/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-usemin/package.json...OK
Loading "usemin.js" tasks...OK
+ usemin, useminPrepare

Registering "grunt-wiredep" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/package.json...OK
Loading "wiredep.js" tasks...OK
+ wiredep
Initializing config...OK
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ build, default, serve, server, test

Running tasks: build

Running "build" task

Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
Verifying property clean.dist exists in config...OK
Files: [no src]
Options: force=false, no-write=false
Options: force=false, no-write=false

Running "wiredep" task

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Verifying property wiredep.app exists in config...OK
Files: app/index.html
Verifying property wiredep.app.src exists in config...OK
Options: src=["app/index.html"], ignorePath={}

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task
Verifying property wiredep.sass exists in config...OK
Files: app/styles/main.scss
Verifying property wiredep.sass.src exists in config...OK
Options: src=["app/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}"], ignorePath={}

Running "useminPrepare" task

Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Verifying property useminPrepare.html exists in config...OK
Files: app/index.html -> html
Options: dest="dist", flow={"html":{"steps":{"js":["concat","uglifyjs"],"css":["cssmin"]},"post":{}}}
Going through app/index.html to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks

Configuration is now:

  concat:
  { generated: 
   { files: 
      [ { dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts/oldieshim.js',
          src: 
           [ 'bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js ',
             'bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js ' ] },
        { dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts/vendor.js',
          src: 
           [ 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
             'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
             'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
             'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
             'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
             'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
             'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
             'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
             'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
             'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
             'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js' ] },
        { dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js',
          src: 
           [ '{.tmp,app}/scripts/app.js ',
             '{.tmp,app}/scripts/controllers/main.js ' ] } ] } }

  uglify:
  { generated: 
   { files: 
      [ { dest: 'dist/scripts/oldieshim.js',
          src: [ '.tmp/concat/scripts/oldieshim.js' ] },
        { dest: 'dist/scripts/vendor.js',
          src: [ '.tmp/concat/scripts/vendor.js' ] },
        { dest: 'dist/scripts/scripts.js',
          src: [ '.tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js' ] } ] } }

  cssmin:
  { generated: 
   { files: 
      [ { dest: 'dist/styles/vendor.css',
          src: [ 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' ] },
        { dest: 'dist/styles/main.css',
          src: [ '.tmp/styles/main.css' ] } ] } }

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task
Verifying property concurrent.dist exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> dist
Options: limit=8
    Warning: Initializing
    Command-line options: --verbose

    Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

    Registering Gruntfile tasks.

    Registering "grunt-autoprefixer" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json...OK
    Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...OK
    + autoprefixer

    Registering "grunt-concurrent" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
    Loading "concurrent.js" tasks...OK
    + concurrent

    Registering "grunt-contrib-clean" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
    Loading "clean.js" tasks...OK
    + clean

    Registering "grunt-contrib-compass" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
    Loading "compass.js" tasks...OK
    + compass

    Registering "grunt-contrib-concat" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
    Loading "concat.js" tasks...OK
    + concat

    Registering "grunt-contrib-connect" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
    Loading "connect.js" tasks...OK
    + connect

    Registering "grunt-contrib-copy" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/package.json...OK
    Loading "copy.js" tasks...OK
    + copy

    Registering "grunt-contrib-cssmin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
    Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...OK
    + cssmin

    Registering "grunt-contrib-htmlmin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/package.json...OK
    Loading "htmlmin.js" tasks...OK
    + htmlmin

    Registering "grunt-contrib-imagemin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
    Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> Error: Cannot find module 'bin-wrapper'
    >>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    >>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    >>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    >>     at require (module.js:380:17)
    >>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle/lib/index.js:3:18)
    >>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    >>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    >>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    >>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    >>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

    Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
    Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
    + jshint

    Registering "grunt-contrib-uglify" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
    Loading "uglify.js" tasks...OK
    + uglify

    Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
    Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
    + watch

    Registering "grunt-filerev" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-filerev/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-filerev/package.json...OK
    Loading "filerev.js" tasks...OK
    + filerev

    Registering "grunt-google-cdn" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/package.json...OK
    Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...OK
    + cdnify

    Registering "grunt-newer" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-newer/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-newer/package.json...OK
    Loading "newer.js" tasks...OK
    + any-newer, newer, newer-clean, newer-postrun

    Registering "grunt-ng-annotate" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/package.json...OK
    Loading "ng-annotate.js" tasks...OK
    + ngAnnotate

    Registering "grunt-svgmin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
    Loading "svgmin.js" tasks...OK
    + svgmin

    Registering "grunt-usemin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-usemin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-usemin/package.json...OK
    Loading "usemin.js" tasks...OK
    + usemin, useminPrepare

    Registering "grunt-wiredep" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/package.json...OK
    Parsing /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolution/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/package.json...OK
    Loading "wiredep.js" tasks...OK
    + wiredep
    Initializing config...OK
    Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
    + build, default, serve, server, test

    Running tasks: compass:dist

    Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
    Verifying property compass.dist exists in config...OK
    File: [no files]
    Options: sassDir="app/styles", cssDir=".tmp/styles", generatedImagesDir="dist/images/generated", imagesDir="app/images", javascriptsDir="app/scripts", fontsDir="app/styles/fonts", importPath="./bower_components", httpImagesPath="/images", httpGeneratedImagesPath="/images/generated", httpFontsPath="/styles/fonts", relativeAssets=false, assetCacheBuster=false, raw="Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n"
    Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


    Execution Time (2015-01-27 14:27:21 UTC)
    loading tasks   5ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 28%
    compass:dist   12ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 67%
    Total 18ms Use --force to continue.

        Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-01-27 14:27:19 UTC)
loading tasks         6ms  0%
clean:dist            6ms  0%
wiredep:app         185ms  ▇▇▇▇▇ 10%
wiredep:sass         11ms  ▇ 1%
useminPrepare:html   18ms  ▇ 1%
concurrent:dist      1.7s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 88%
Total 1.9s

pdc1-f3t18r1:ShippingSolution administrator$
```

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and I found that in the build process there is a task in the grunt file the uses ngAnnotate.

So I check on the package.config and I saw that package for grung-ng-annotate was missing so I went through their page and update it.

Use this to install it

```
npm install grunt-ng-annotate --save-dev
```

This will add your package to the config and then you will be able to run the "grunt" task without a problem and generate the "dist" folder.

https://github.com/mzgol/grunt-ng-annotate For more information.